# How to select complete line of paragraph with mouse by using offset or drag/drop?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcqCT.png)I want to select this text line with mouse:

Today is the age of education we cannot neglect the importance of science an Technology.

To achieve this I am using below code but it starts selecting from middle, I want to select from first word till the end.

```
    IWebElement iscop = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='idRequirement']/div/span[1]/p"));//find element

    string text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='idRequirement']/div/span[1]/p")).Text;//get element text

        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
       int length = text.Length;
        actions.DragAndDropToOffset(iscop, 75, 0);

        actions.ClickAndHold(iscop);
        actions.MoveByOffset(75, 0);
        actions.Release(iscop);
        actions.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML and image of the UI?

Comment: Why do you want to select the text?

Comment: Selected text will be copied in a text box.

Comment: Is it not possible to do iscop. Text?

Comment: @pankaj yes i got the text with .text but then i want to copy the first line with mouse. Actually the flow is like this: i select some text with mouse and when drop the mouse this text will place in the text box.

Comment: I attached an image to view which i really want.

Comment: You can also either drag and drop the whole text or you and trim the text you are getting from the IWebElement iscop

Comment: simple drag drop does not copy the whole text.